# UItableView Displaying Duplicate Cells, Whats Wrong with my Data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

[image]

Not sure what to do at this point..... I've been stuck for days of constant trying.

I was using the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azFjJZxZP6M&index=12&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq).

I used his code structure, as I'm a beginner and it seemed like best practice. The duplicate cell also has the inaccurate time sent and first message. I really need help.

Here is the message controller (the screen you see above):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class MessagesViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var messagesLabelOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var messagesTableView: UITableView!

var newUser : User?
var messageArr = [Message]()
var messageDict = [String: Message]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    messagesTableView.dataSource = self
    messagesTableView.delegate = self;
    self.messagesTableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
    messageArr.removeAll()
    messageDict.removeAll()
    messagesTableView.reloadData()
    observeUserMessages()
    configureTableView()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messageArr.count;
}

func configureTableView()
{
    messagesTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    messagesTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.newUser = User()

    if let chatPartnerId = messageArr[indexPath.row].chatPartnerId(){
        self.newUser?.toId! = chatPartnerId;



    let chatPartnerDataRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(chatPartnerId)

    chatPartnerDataRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else{
            return

        }
            self.newUser?.userName = dict["username"] as? String
            self.newUser?.picURL = dict["pic"] as? String
            self.newUser?.score = dict["score"] as? String


        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToChatLogControllerPlzFromMessages", sender: self)

    }
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    let message = messageArr[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Book" , size: 19);
    cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Light" , size: 14);

    cell.message = message;



    return cell;
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // do not remove
    if segue.identifier == "goToChatLogControllerPlzFromMessages"{
        print("going to chat log")
    let recieveVC = segue.destination as! ChatLogController

    if let textUser = newUser{
        recieveVC.user = textUser;

    }
    }

}

func checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
{

    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil{
        print("uid is nil")

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "noUserFoundGoingBackToLogin", sender: self);

    }
    else{
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        })
    }
}

func observeUserMessages(){

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{
        checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
        return;
    }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid)

    ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let messageId = snapshot.key
        let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            // no duplicate texts as of here
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            {
                let message = Message()
                message.fromId = dict["fromid"] as? String;
                message.text = dict["text"] as? String;
                message.timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? String;
                message.toId = dict["toid"] as? String;

                self.messageArr.append(message)

                if let toID = message.toId{

                    for m in self.messageArr{
                        if message.toId == m.toId && m.fromId == message.fromId || message.toId == m.fromId && m.fromId == message.toId{
                            self.messageDict[toID] = message;

                        }
                    }


                    self.messageArr = Array(self.messageDict.values)
                    self.messageArr.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in

                        let time1 = Int(truncating: (message1.timestamp?.numberValue)!)
                        let time2 = Int(truncating: (message2.timestamp?.numberValue)!)

                        return time1 > time2
                    })


                }



                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(message.text!)
                    self.messagesTableView.reloadData()
                }

            }


        })
    }


}

}
```

I have narrowed down the error to this method :

```
func observeUserMessages(){

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{
        checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
        return;
    }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid)

    ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let messageId = snapshot.key
        let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            // no duplicate texts as of here
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            {
                let message = Message()
                message.fromId = dict["fromid"] as? String;
                message.text = dict["text"] as? String;
                message.timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? String;
                message.toId = dict["toid"] as? String;

                self.messageArr.append(message)

                if let toID = message.toId{

                    for m in self.messageArr{
                        if message.toId == m.toId && m.fromId == message.fromId || message.toId == m.fromId && m.fromId == message.toId{
                            self.messageDict[toID] = message;

                        }
                    }


                    self.messageArr = Array(self.messageDict.values)
                    self.messageArr.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in

                        let time1 = Int(truncating: (message1.timestamp?.numberValue)!)
                        let time2 = Int(truncating: (message2.timestamp?.numberValue)!)

                        return time1 > time2
                    })


                }



                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(message.text!)
                    self.messagesTableView.reloadData()
                }

            }


        })
    }


}
```

I have found that using this for loop, I either load all the users or get duplicates.

```
 for m in self.messageArr{
                        if message.toId == m.toId && m.fromId == 
message.fromId || message.toId == m.fromId && m.fromId == message.toId{
                            self.messageDict[toID] = message;

                        }
                    }
```

Thank you for anyone who wants to help.

**UPDATE**

I solved the issue after 4 f***ing days. the solution was in the data , I was loading data that had toID and fromID that were the same. thanks for everyones help

Comment: "message.toId == m.fromId && m.fromId == message.toId" Both sides of the && look like they're identical just in different order...is that a typo?  I'd also recommend using parenthesis to be extra clear on how that evaluates (I'm pretty sure && has precedence over ||, but just to be safe).

Answer (score 0):

The cells get reused, meaning they retain the previous UI info.  In your CellForRowAt method, you need to explicitly set the image, person name, timestamp, etc.

Comment: If you're going to downvote what I felt was a valid and useful answer, please provide feedback on why.  It's actually a very common mistake for new users to not realize that when a cell is reused, the UI objects will display the same info they had previously.

Comment: This was my first thought, too. The only customization of the data in the cell is in the assignment `cell.message = message;` and that code is not shown.  The problem is not in the `UITableView`, it's either in `UserCell` or in the data source.

Answer (score 0):

it may be caused because you are always appending to the array the same values when getting snapshot from firebase 
try to check array for duplicates 
to prevent same image in cells just set image to nil then provide desired image or provide image  placeholder because cells are always reused